# How to get a circle inside a div?

Tags: jquery, html, raphael

I need to have a circle inside the div. I'm using RaphaelJs.
I'm using RaphaelJS for having vector images(cirlce) on my UI. Simultaneously, I'm having [jQueryUI sortable](http://www.jqueryui.com/sortable/) on my page as well.

So, when specify var paper = new Raphael(x, y, width, height); for making a canvas, the section of portlets coming under x and y co-ordinates does not seem to work, as in I'm not able to move/drag the portlets. For eg:- If x and y is set as 300 and 300, the portlets in 1st column does drags and 2nd and 3rd works properly. Upon increasing the x and y values(say 800,800), all the portlets does not drags at all.

I guess on creating canvas in RaphaelJS , the portion coming under canvas does not function as it should. How can I rectify it? Or is there any other alternative to it?

**Here is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shap Design with Raphael</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {  
                var paper = new Raphael(20,20, 300, 300);  
                var p = paper.path("M 250 250 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");  

                p.attr(  
                    {  
                        gradient: '90-#526c7a-#64a0c1',  
                        stroke: '#3b4449',  
                        'stroke-width': 10,  
                        'stroke-linejoin': 'round',  
                        rotation: -90  
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
            #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
            #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
              $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
              $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try running this code on [this link](http://www.compileonline.com/try_raphael_online.php). Copy and paste the code.

Comment: Any other alternative other than RaphaelJS is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of your div, then use them as parameters of Raphael functions which need coordination. For example to draw a circle inside a div:

```
<div style="background-color:yellow" id='div1'>
here is the div
<script>
var p = $('#div1');
var position = p.position();

var paper = Raphael(10, position.left, position.left + 320, position.top + 200);
var circle = paper.circle(position.left, position.top, 10);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const container = document.createElement('DIV');

function drawCircle(){
  for(o=0;o<59;o++){
 container.innerHTML+='<span id="o'+o+'" style="position:absolute;">&bull;</span>'; 
}
  
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  for(o=0;o<59;o++){
    eval('o'+o).style.left=Math.sin(o/9.2)*120+120+"px";
    eval('o'+o).style.top=Math.cos(o/9.2)*120+120+"px";
  }
}drawCircle();
```